# Default constructor of class Exception?

Tags: java, exception, constructor

```
package com.psl.exception;

public class NoDataFoundException extends Exception {

    public NoDataFoundException(){
        super("No Data Found");
    }

    public NoDataFoundException(String msg){
        super(msg);
    }
}
```

What does the class Exception do with the string that is passed? I tried it and it does nothing. What is the point of passing the string to the constructor of Exception then?

Answer (score 1):

It sets `String` passed as message in [`Throwable`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Throwable.java#Throwable.%3Cinit%3E%28java.lang.String%29), which is generally a useful custom message which gets printed when exception is thrown, also can be retrieved by `getMessage()` method on `Throwable`

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html#Exception-java.lang.String-) says:

> Constructs a new exception with the specified detail message.

The detail message is available from [`getMessage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getMessage--) and usually included in `toString` and such.

Answer (score 0):

One of the constructors of Exception takes a string to use as the detail message.

See here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html

The default constructor uses a null detail message, but other components such as a message and throwable can be specified